# (Mac) Rollover Buttons in IB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder

Does anyone know the best way to create rollover buttons in IB? I tried a square button with image/alt image but nothing happens upon rollover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an AMRollOverButton Project that comes with an Interface Builder pLugin. haven't tested it yet but have a look at it(at the section code):
http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php

Answer (score 1):

if you're after what i believe you're after, then see:

```
 -[NSResponder mouseEntered:]
 -[NSResponder mouseExited:]
```

and family. on enter/exit, change the image (or do whatever changes you like).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. You'd also need an NSTrackingArea added to the NSButton (the view itself).

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi that's one option, introduced in 10.5. in the olde days, we accomplished (iirc) mouse event forwarding to views by enabling `-[NSWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:]` -- but i'm not really inclined to dig through implementations this minute to verify every last detail.

Comment: I'm aware of the pre-10.5 era. :-) Before this there were tracking rects. Either way, you needed a bit more than to implement -mouseEntered: and -mouseExited:. Since we're rounding the corner to "three major OS version ago" I tend to give at least a 10.5 or above answer unless asked otherwise.